# ChromeDriver Not Working Even After Updating to Latest Version

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

A couple of months ago Selenium worked flawlessly, but when I ran my program this morning it was not working. The current Chrome browser version is 102.0.5005.63. I downloaded the the latest version of ChromeDriver (ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61) and restarted the computer. I am still getting the same error message:

"*This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 102.0.5005.63 with binary path...[insert path here]*"

I have placed the ChromeDriver on my desktop, in the folder that the Python file is contained in, and in the binary path where Chrome is stored. Nothing changes; I always get the same error message.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Thank you

Comment: sometimes you have to wait for driver which can work with the newest browser - or you have to use little older browser.

Comment: you downloaded the newest driver but maybe you still use older driver in code - you may have to change path to driver in code. Error shows that you still use wrong driver.

Comment: you can also use module [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) and it will automatically download correct driver and it will use correct path in code.

Comment: Hello @furas. I tried that. Unfortunately that did not work and I receive the same error message.

Comment: did you use it as in documentation? `webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` ?

Comment: if you still have the same error it still uses the same driver. You have to remove it and install new one (which can work with newer browser), or you have remove browser and install older version (which works with current driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross the exact same issue but with nodejs.  the way I fixed it was deleting the node_modules folder then reinstalling all dependicies , maybe you can do something similar like that to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same issue and solved it by updating all related packages.